# SharePoint Primer

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I recently started working on my first SharePoint (2007) project (C#), so I was wondering if anyone can point me to some good resources that will get me up and running with SharePoint programming basics quickly.  I'd like to have a deeper understanding of the various terms I'm hearing such as Features, Lists, wsp, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best resources is Ted Pattison's [Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201). Great resource, especially if you are okay with purchasing a book.

Comment: Thanks. So, what's the difference between SharePoint Services 3.0 and SharePoint Server 2007?

Comment: WSS is the free version that you get with licensed version of Windows various Server OSes. SP Server 2007 is the more advanced version that consists of BDC, improved search, Excel Services, etc. From the programming standpoint, the majority of what you are concerned with for document libraries, list items, features, etc is in the standard WSS.

Answer (score 1):

this should help
[Sharepoint Best Practices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb736746.aspx)

sharepoint 2007 trainning kit
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7BB3A2A3-6A9F-49F4-84E8-FF3FB71046DF&displaylang=en

Office SharePoint Server 2007 Training

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=673DC932-626A-4E59-9DCA-16D685600A51&displaylang=en